# XQUERY - how to get xml filename

Tags: xquery, filenames

I have a xml file $doc, I want to retrieve its file name so I use base-uri($doc) or document-uri($doc) with this result: "file:/C:/Users/Desktop/corpus/Decree.xml".
How can I get just "Decree.xml"?

Answer (score 2):

Use `tokenize` and select the last token e.g. `tokenize(base-uri($doc), '/')[last()]`.